# Alter the column default value for an existing column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing column (`ROLE`) whose default value needs to be updated from *'zzzz'* to *'S'*.

I tried using the below query, which obviously doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE [TRANSACTIONS] ALTER COLUMN [ROLE] ADD DEFAULT('S') ;
```

Can someone please help understand if it is even possible to update the column default value and if yes, then how?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to drop and re-add the default constraint to specify a different value.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TRANSACTIONS DROP CONSTRAINT DF_TRANSACTIONS_ROLE;
ALTER TABLE dbo.TRANSACTIONS ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TRANSACTIONS_ROLE DEFAULT ('S') FOR [ROLE];
```

However, since you didn't explicitly name the constraint (which is a best practice), you'll need to determine the existing constraint name for the `DROP` statement:

```
SELECT name
FROM sys.default_constraints AS dc
WHERE
    dc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TRANSACTIONS')
    AND dc.parent_column_id = COLUMNPROPERTYEX(dc.parent_object_id, 'ROLE', 'ColumnID');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS DROP CONSTRAINT DF__TRANSACTIO__ROLE__48CFD27E;
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD DEFAULT('S') FOR ROLE
```

Comment: They are trying to update an existing default. This will give `Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.`

Comment: Updated it, but please change the constraint name to match

Comment: Yes, it throws the below error: "Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it."

Comment: Please try the updated answer but update DF__TRANSACTIO__ROLE__48CFD27E to match your constraint name

Answer (score 2):

You need to look up the name of the current default constraint. Suppose it is named `DefaultConstraintName`, then you would execute this query:

```
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS DROP CONSTRAINT DefaultConstraintName;
GO
ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ADD CONSTRAINT DF_TRANSACTIONS_ROLE DEFAULT ('S') FOR ROLE;
GO
```

Since you showed us the code you would use to create a constraint, your existing constraint name is probably generated by SQL Server having a part of a GUID in it's name. This is not good practice and it's always good to name your constraints as I have in the above code example.